# ArrayAdapter getFilter() with RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-arrayadapter, rx-android

I have a `SearchView` in my activity and have added `onQueryTextChange` listener.
I have also added custom class which extends `Filter` class. There I have added RxJava observer as you can see on the below code. But the problem it I have to return `FilteretedResults` from the class but RxJava's observer's `onComplete` method's return type is void. So my filtered results is always null and crashes the app as I am doing some stuff with that filtered results. What will be the correct way of doing this if I want to do the string matching in background as list contains around 2500 records without blocking the UI?

```
private class ValueFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(final CharSequence charSequence) {
        final FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();
        final List<SubCategorySingle> subCategorySinglesLocal=new ArrayList<>();

        Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(ObservableEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
                emitter.onNext(charSequence+"");
            }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {

                if(charSequence !=null && charSequence.length()>0){
                    for(int i=0;i<subCategoryList.getSubCategorySingles().size();i++){
                        if(subCategoryList.getSubCategorySingles().get(i).getName().toUpperCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toUpperCase())){
                            subCategorySinglesLocal.add(subCategoryList.getSubCategorySingles().get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.count=subCategorySinglesLocal.size();
                    filterResults.values=subCategorySinglesLocal;
                }else{
                    filterResults.count=subCategoryList.getSubCategorySingles().size();
                    filterResults.values=subCategoryList.getSubCategorySingles();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                filterResults.notifyAll();
            }
        });

        return filterResults;

    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        setupCategoryForSearch((List<SubCategorySingle>)filterResults.values);
    }
}

private void setupCategoryForSearch(List<SubCategorySingle> values) {
    catHolder.removeAllViews();
    progressBar.smoothToShow();
    for(int i=0;i<values.size();i++){
        addCategory(values.get(i));
    }
    progressBar.smoothToHide();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the docs of [`Filter#performFiltering(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html#performFiltering(java.lang.CharSequence)):

> **Invoked in a worker thread** to filter the data according to the constraint. Subclasses must implement this method to perform the filtering operation. Results computed by the filtering operation must be returned as a `Filter.FilterResults` that **will then be published in the UI thread** through `publishResults(CharSequence, android.widget.Filter.FilterResults)`.

So, `performFiltering()` will run on a background thread by default, you are getting that feature out of the box, no need to take carry of performing your long-running operation on a background thread via Rx approach (in fact you can't even do it, because the API of `ArrayAdapter` does **not** give such abilities).